# Dispatcher Configuration For Better Performance:Akka Persistence/DDD/CQRS

Tags: akka-persistence

I working on an app using akka persistence,akka remoting,akka sharding. We are taking DDD/CQRS approach.

Below is the app configuration,

```
akka {
    loglevel = INFO

  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 9088
         }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://akkaworld@127.0.0.1:9088"
         ]
    auto-down-unreachable-after = 20s
  }

  persistence {
    journal.plugin = "cassandra-journal"

  }
}
```

We are creating one actor system for entire app. Correct me if I am wrong, the default dispatcher by default uses a fork-join thread pool with at least 8 threads.

We need to support millions of requests from client. How to tune dispatcher of actor system when using akka persistence/sharding/clustering,
What is Recommended Type of Dispatcher
How to calculate threads per thread pool
Do we need to consider cores?
Do we need to consider type of OS
Will JVM configuration matter
[Note:] Suggest any missed parameter in above list. Also how to specify custom dispatcher configuration in app conf.

Basically want to understand criteria's to decide performing dispatcher per actor system.

Is there any other configuration required to tune akka persistence/cluster/shard kind of application for good performance.

Also recommendations for tuning akka persistence/cluster/shard kind of application would be great help.

-Prakhyat M M

Comment: hi, wondering if you can share you learnings